# I'm getting a compile time error that I don't know how to solve: error: expecting property name or receiver type - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
/**
 * Example:
 * var li = ListNode(5)
 * var v = li.`val`
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * class ListNode(var `val`: Int) {
 *     var next: ListNode? = null
 * }
 */


class Solution {

  fun mergeTwoLists(l1: ListNode?, l2: ListNode?): ListNode? {
    var head : ListNode? 
    var tail: ListNode? 
    var firstPointer : ListNode? = l1
    var secondPointer : ListNode? = l2

    while( firstPointer != null || secondPointer != null){
        var next : ListNode? 
        if (firstPointer == null || secondPointer == null){
            if (secondPointer != null){
                next.val = secondPointer.val
                secondPointer = secondPointer.next 
            }else {
                next.val = firstPointer.val 
                firstPointer = firstPointer.next
            }
        }else if(firstPointer.val <= secondPointer.val) {
            next.val = firstPointer.val
            firstPointer = firstPointer.next
        }else if(secondPointer.val <= firstPointer.val ){
            next.val = secondPointer.val 
            secondPointer = secondPointer.next
        }
        
        if (head == null){
            head = next
            tail = next
        }else {
            tail.next = next
            tail = next
        }
    }        
    return head
}
}
```

getting a lot of compile time errors

Line 22: Char 29: error: expecting property name or receiver type
next.val = secondPointer.val
^
Line 25: Char 29: error: expecting property name or receiver type
next.val = firstPointer.val
^
Line 28: Char 39: error: type expected
}else if(firstPointer.val <= secondPointer.val) {
^

Answer (score 3):

`val` is a keyword in kotlin. If you want to use it as a name of a field, you need to wrap it into backticks: `` secondPointer.`val` ``, `` firstPointer.`val` `` (actualy, code example in the comment before your code shows that).

Comment: Also, naming your property `\`val\`` is purposely making your code hard to read and write.

Comment: In fact, the question itself has a clue: in `firstPointer.val`, StackOverflow's code formatter shows the `val` in a different colour (matching the other keywords).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know Kotlin well, but from my perspective this might be the problem:

```
var next : ListNode?
```

Because you define a variable, but it is still `null`.
When you then try to access its field `val` you can't, because `null` has no such field.

Comment: It isn't even null if there is no initial value given. The problem is trying to read the variable before any initial value has been set on it. Kotlin doesn't assume an initial value of null for a variable. Neither does Java for local variables.